# Layout Help Fitting to Any Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Hi I have an issue with trying to fit my storyboard objects to other iphone device screens using autolayout. I need to adjust the vertical spacing between my the 4% rule and the get started stack views to fit it but it changes the layout on the iphone 11 pro screen. How can I have everything be in the same position for both screens?

[image: iphone 11 pro screen]

[image: iphone se second screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the priority of the 2 stackviews from 1000 to 750, and it seems to have fixed my issue.